# Approx count of UI screens in a angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to know if there is a way to get total count of UI screens in a angular application ? I know by doing global search on code base using component.ts I can get component count but I don’t want it I need screen count since some of the components render in parent component and it doesn’t count as multiple screens ..any tools or search method which will get me approximate screen count?

Comment: Might be helpful if you define the problem you are trying to solve, and what you strictly mean by "screens". There may be tools which can help, e.g. the Augury chrome extension has a routing map (https://augury.rangle.io/pages/guides/routes.html) which is effectively the number of "screens", although this wouldn't be helpful if you were trying to check "how many times is my component rendered per route" as a given route can have multiple sub-configurations/views depending on how you have architected your app